# Footer wrapping ul doesn't stick to bottom

Tags: css, flexbox, sticky-footer

I have a simple HTML layout with header, content and footer.

Inside the footer I have an unordered list (`<ul>`).

I'm using Flexbox to enforce the footer stick to the bottom of the page.

While usually it works very well for me, in this situation it doesn't.

Here is a [Codepan](https://codepen.io/bagilad/pen/PEeYwy).

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

header,
footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>
<section class="content">
  Content
</section>
<footer>
  <ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Again, without the ul the footer does stick to the bottom.
But with the `<ul>`, it doesn't.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it dangerous to do what you do ? Fix a layout on the viewport height is not very recommanded. Of courses it's depending on how much content you have. But if this is on a phone, you content area will be very very small. Can you describe me more your project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set height of the footer to only 100px. The UL exceeds that. Change:

```
height: 100px;
```

To:

```
min-height: 100px;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have set the footer and the header height to 100px, that's what causing it to not work properly.
Remove the height property from your footer and your div size will depend on the content inside of it.